# How to align first column with vim-easy-align?

Tags: plugin-easy-align

Not sure how to align the first column with EasyAlign.

Visual select below two lines and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>

```
   wr_strobe <= abc dc asdf  
            rd_strobe <= asd sdfk asdfasd
```

Only first column is not aligned.

```
   wr_strobe          <= abc dc   asdf
            rd_strobe <= asd sdfk asdfasd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that the default setting of vim-easy-align is to keep the current indentation. You can get the desired alignment with `ga<c-i>*<space>`.

I find the EasyAlignLign feature to be very useful for this sort of thing. If you map e.g. `gA` to `<plug>(LiveEasyAlign)`, then visually select your text and do `gA`. Now you can see how your current settings work. E.g., `gA*<space><c-i><space>` would give the same result as above, except you would see the changes as you apply the settings.